# How to grant a serviceAccount the editor role only on their own pubsub subscriptions

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iam

I want a service account to be able to (at runtime) create a subscription and attach it to a specific topic, and then allow that serviceAccount to also get/update/delete/consume that specific subscription they just created, but not the other subscriptions in the project.

Is this possible? I don't see any way to grant a role to a principal only for the resources they created themselves. Since they'll create the resource at runtime, I can't ahead of time grant them the role on the resource, since it doesn't exist yet.

The only place I see I can grant them a role ahead of time is the project level, which grants them the role on ALL subscriptions, not just the ones they created themselves. I just want to give them
`pubsub.subscriptions.create` at the project level, `pubsub.topics.attachSubscription` for a specific topic (already sorted), and then `roles/pubsub.editor` on their own subscription. Its that last one that I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: No, you have the chicken-and-egg scenario. Granting an identity the permission to create resources is an administrator-level permission. That permission must be granted at the project level or higher. There are some tricks you can do with IAM conditions using resource tag conditions, but I have not tested that with Pub/Sub IAM roles. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/tags-access-control

Comment: Yeah, its weird that creating a subscription is an admin level operation. You need to have a subscription to subscribe to something. And if you don't know the subscriptions ahead of time (because they are dynamic), then that basically means subscribing to messages also becomes an admin level operation. It just doesn't make sense to me. But your link is helpful, thanks.